# How to clear all the other fields within the form once users start to input in one of fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have 6 `<input>` fields in a form:

```
<form>
    <input id="input1" />
    <input id="input2" />
    <input id="input3" />
    <input id="input4" />
    <input id="input5" />
    <input id="input6" />
</form>
```

Once the user starts to type something in one of the 6 input fields, I want to clear all of the *other* inputs.

What is an efficient way to do this?

I have tried the following:

```
$('input').keypress(function() {
    $('input').reset();
});
```

But this event will be fired *every* `keypress` -- not just the first. Is there a way to do this more efficiently?

Comment: So you can effectively only have text in only one textbox at a time? Is that the point?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: @Ian Yes. that's the point!

Comment: The answer is basic jquery.  And if you are only going to let the user enter data into a single input, why have multiple inputs?

Comment: `formElement.elements` holds an a Array of input fields in raw JavaScript. You could use `onkeydown` in your loop, since it doesn't matter what the input is. If it did matter what the input was, you would want to use the `onkeyup` Event.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
jQuery('input').keyup(function() {
    $(this).siblings().val('')
})
```

[Try it out.](http://jsfiddle.net/eP7mB/)

Comment: I have tried something similar (not exactly the same thing though. I tried keydown event).I guess this will be fired every time when keyup happened not just the first.

Comment: It'll be called every key press but it doesn't matter (really), as you can see it works pretty well, and doing anything else would require a lot more code (read: bugs) and you still need to check *every single key press*, so it's not worth it :)

Comment: Ok. you got the point which kinda convinces me. I will award you.